# preg_replace and hex russian language not readable

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters

im currently a little bit confused about this problem:

```
$string = "делик - Mo. - Mai (500)";
$x = preg_replace('/[\\x20-\\x2F\\x3a-\\x40\\x5b-\\x60\\x7b-\\xc2]/', '', $string);
echo $string."\n";
echo $x."\n";
```

im trying to remove all special chars like !"§$%&/()=?`*'-:;#...

the output will be:

```
делик - Mo. - Mai (500)
▒▒▒▒▒MoMai500
```

so after the preg_replace was started, the string with russian chars are not readable anymore.

any ideas?

Thanks Advance!

Comment: Try to work with the `/u`  modifier and unicode character properties while using UTF-8.

Comment: For instance with Unicode ranges `\x{0400}-\x{04ff}` or `\p{Cyrillic}` in `/u` mode.

Comment: Big Thanks Wrikken and mario ;-) This was the solution ;-)